# How to call browser.get only once in a script?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, automation, jasmine, protractor

I am new to protractor, right now I am putting browser.get(URL) within the first 'it' statement and then for my `afterEach` statement I make the browser go back to the homepage.

I am wondering if there's a better place to put the browser.get statement to make my tests more module?  I tried putting it within a beforeEach statement but I don't want to open a new browser for EVERY test that I'm running. Is there a better place to put these pre-condition items?

Any other tips for a beginner would be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to call `browser.get()` only once for all of the tests in the suite, use [`beforeAll()`](http://jasmine.github.io/2.3/introduction.html#section-10):

> The `beforeAll` function is called only once before all the specs in
>   describe are run, and the `afterAll` function is called after all specs
>   finish. These functions can be used to speed up test suites with
>   expensive setup and teardown.

```
describe('My page', function() {
    beforeAll(function() {
        browser.get('/the/url');
    });

    it('test 1', function() {
        // ...  
    });

    it('test 2', function() {
        // ...  
    });
});
```

`beforeAll` is built-in to jasmine2. In case of jasmine1, there is a third-party [`jasmine-beforeAll`](https://github.com/nonplus/jasmine-beforeAll) package that provides the same exact functionality.

Comment: For some reason beforeAll isn't working for me... ReferenceError: beforeAll is not defined.  Would you recommend just upgrading to jasmine 2?

Comment: @Bieksa have you installed `jasmine-beforeAll`?

Answer (score 0):

You want to stick your `browser.get()` call in a [beforeEach](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Setup_and_Teardown) method:

```js
describe('My page', function() {
  beforeEach(function() {
    browser.get('/the/url');
  });

  it('should load', function() {
    // Some verification logic
  });
});
```

Comment: what if i just wanted to run it once for a bunch of it's?